# Show/hide div onmouseover/onmouseout Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have a hyperlink on my page.  I want to show a div when I mouse over the hyperlink, and hide it when I mouseout.

My html:

```
<a onmouseover="showDiv(this)" onmouseout="hideDiv(this)">
    <img>
    <div class="inner-block">
         Content
    </div>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function showDiv(elem) {
    elem.getElementsByTagName("div").style.visibility="visible";
}

function hideDiv(elem) {
    elem.getElementsByClassName("inner-block2").style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

and CSS:

```
.inner-block {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

I've tried getElementsByTagName, getElementsByClassName, whatever I try I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined
```

Comment: Is the closing of the a tag after that div?

Comment: Yes, The closing of the a tag is after the div-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
function showDiv(elem) {
    elem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.visibility="visible";
}

function hideDiv(elem) {
    elem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.visibility = "hidden"
}
```

since getElementsByClassName("inner-block2") will return NodeList

Comment: I try this and now I get the issue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: @deakolt i made a change, try now

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I tried that.  Now I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined during the mouseover event

Comment: btw when are you loading your javascript? put your script after the dom ready. that means put it before the closing body tag. coz above solution is working fine for me

Comment: I'm still not sure what's up with this.  Curiously, elem.getElementsByTagName("img")[0] works fine, but elem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0] is not working.